# Change active navbar color for scrollspy

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, scrollspy

I'm using Bootstrap scrollspy to update a navbar. I want to change the color of the highlighted active `li` on the `navbar` to match the `background-color` of the matching section.but it is **dynamic content**

I know what `data-spy` attribute does and how to use it, but I do not know how the scrollspy plugin really works under the bonnet.so i can make a own code to work on it.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>
  body {
      position: relative; 
  }
  #section1 {padding-top:50px;height:500px;color: #fff; background-color: #1E88E5;}
  #section2 {padding-top:50px;height:500px;color: #fff; background-color: #673ab7;}
  #section3 {padding-top:50px;height:500px;color: #fff; background-color: #ff9800;}
  #section41 {padding-top:50px;height:500px;color: #fff; background-color: #00bcd4;}
  #section42 {padding-top:50px;height:500px;color: #fff; background-color: #009688;}
  </style>
</head>
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" data-offset="50">

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><a href="#section1">Section 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#section2">Section 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#section3">Section 3</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Section 4 <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#section41">Section 4-1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#section42">Section 4-2</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>    

<div id="section1" class="container-fluid">
  <h1>Section 1</h1>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
</div>
<div id="section2" class="container-fluid">
  <h1>Section 2</h1>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
</div>
<div id="section3" class="container-fluid">
  <h1>Section 3</h1>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
</div>
<div id="section41" class="container-fluid">
  <h1>Section 4 Submenu 1</h1>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
</div>
<div id="section42" class="container-fluid">
  <h1>Section 4 Submenu 2</h1>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

above is the example of scrollspy. The Scrollspy plugin is used to automatically update links in a navigation list based on scroll position. need is to change color of active navbar to background color of respective position
[This is an example of what I am starting with.](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_scrollspy&stacked=h)

Comment: I suggested an edit to clarify your actual question. Asking generally how a plugin works is too broad and will result in your question getting closed. Please read my suggested edit carefully to make sure it's still asking what you want. Also, it might help if you posted whatever code you have so far instead of linking to W3Schools. Cheers!

Comment: @AndrewMyers I didn't found any ways to achieve it that is why I don't have any code do you think my question is unclear i.e didn't I ask about what I am trying to do

Comment: Sorry about my previous (now deleted) comment. I had actually already answered and deleted my answer when I had a fit of doubt about the whether I understood the question. I thought that your question was almost to be deleted, but now that someone has kindly pointed out that I can still undelete my answer, it's okay now. Your question no longer qualifies to get deleted tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're wanting to change the background of the active (highlighted) navbar item to match the background of the current section, here's how I would do that:

First, listen to the `activate.bs.scrollspy` event. This event fires whenever the scrollspy moves to a new section. This would happen on the element with `data-spy="scroll"` or `window` if your scrollspying on the `body` element.

Within that event handler, look for `.active` to figure out which section is active. What you are looking for is an `<a>` element. Dropdown menus are the tricky part since there can be multiple `.active` elements. You need the final one. The way you get there depends on the markup. For the example you linked to, `$('.active').last().children().first()` would work.

With that done, you can grab `href` of the `<a>`, turn it into a class, and apply it to the navbar. You would also need to remove any classes this event has previously applied.

This gets you to have specific classes on the navbar for each section, dynamically applied only when that section is active. The rest is done with CSS.

The CSS will key off your dynamic class and apply a background to the active `a` elements. Bootstrap gets a little annoying here with all the classes that you have to override. For simplicity, I'm getting around it by using an id:

```
#navbar.bg-section2 .active a  {
  background-color: #28a745;
}
```

The `bg-section2` is the dynamically applied class.

That is all that it takes. Below is a live example. Click "Full page" to see it better.

```js
var $navbar = $('#navbar');
var currentClass = 'bg-section1';

$(window).on('activate.bs.scrollspy', function() {
  var $active = $('.active');
  var $link = $active.last().children().last();

  // Classes have the form "bg-id" (with no # in the id)
  var newClass = 'bg-' + $link.attr('href').slice(1);

  $navbar.removeClass(currentClass);
  $navbar.addClass(newClass);

  // Keep track of which class is active
  currentClass = newClass;
});
```

```css
body {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 50px;
}

section {
  padding: 2rem;
  color: #fff;
  min-height: 70vh;
}

#section1,
#navbar.bg-section1 .active>a {
  background-color: #007bff;
}

#section2,
#navbar.bg-section2 .active>a {
  background-color: #28a745;
}

#section3_1,
#navbar.bg-section3_1 .active>a {
  background-color: #ffc107;
}

#section3_2,
#navbar.bg-section3_2 .active>a {
  background-color: #17a2b8;
}

#section3_3,
#navbar.bg-section3_3 .active>a {
  background-color: #dc3545;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" data-offset="50">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar">
         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
      </div>
      <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse bg-section1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><a href="#section1">Section 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#section2">Section 2</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Section 3</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#section3_1">Section 3.1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#section3_2">Section 3.2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#section3_3">Section 3.3</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <section id="section1">
    <h2>Section 1</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Rerum voluptate unde facere cupiditate hic, voluptates nobis reiciendis ipsum autem! Deserunt deleniti libero dolores, provident velit repellat. Deleniti omnis, et ipsa.</p>
  </section>
  <section id="section2">
    <h2>Section 2</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Rerum voluptate unde facere cupiditate hic, voluptates nobis reiciendis ipsum autem! Deserunt deleniti libero dolores, provident velit repellat. Deleniti omnis, et ipsa.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quaerat impedit alias, fugit aliquid, architecto minus nemo nihil odio quam tempore. Odit perspiciatis voluptatum culpa provident. Minus et voluptas facilis delectus.</p>
  </section>
  <section id="section3_1">
    <h2>Section 3.1</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Rerum voluptate unde facere cupiditate hic, voluptates nobis reiciendis ipsum autem! Deserunt deleniti libero dolores, provident velit repellat. Deleniti omnis, et ipsa.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quaerat impedit alias, fugit aliquid, architecto minus nemo nihil odio quam tempore. Odit perspiciatis voluptatum culpa provident. Minus et voluptas facilis delectus.</p>
  </section>
  <section id="section3_2">
    <h2>Section 3.2</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Rerum voluptate unde facere cupiditate hic, voluptates nobis reiciendis ipsum autem! Deserunt deleniti libero dolores, provident velit repellat. Deleniti omnis, et ipsa.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quaerat impedit alias, fugit aliquid, architecto minus nemo nihil odio quam tempore. Odit perspiciatis voluptatum culpa provident. Minus et voluptas facilis delectus.</p>
  </section>
  <section id="section3_3">
    <h2>Section 3.3</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Rerum voluptate unde facere cupiditate hic, voluptates nobis reiciendis ipsum autem! Deserunt deleniti libero dolores, provident velit repellat. Deleniti omnis, et ipsa.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quaerat impedit alias, fugit aliquid, architecto minus nemo nihil odio quam tempore. Odit perspiciatis voluptatum culpa provident. Minus et voluptas facilis delectus.</p>
  </section>
</body>
```